# Creating OBX segments from multiple DB rows

Tags: mirth

I have a DB source which I am transforming into HL7. In the transform, I have a step to connect to the database and retrieve rows for OBX segments, there can be no rows or multiple rows.

I'm successfully getting all the values, but I'm having trouble getting them written into OBX segments. They're all the same, and all the last row retrieved.

Database values:

```
OBX3    OBX5
Test123 This is a new referral
Test456 Person
Test789 Anxiety
```

The result I'm getting in the message is:

```
OBX|0||Test789||Anxiety 
OBX|1||Test789||Anxiety
OBX|2||Test789||Anxiety
```

Code:

```
var erefID = msg['erefid'].toString();
   var dbConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createDatabaseConnection(driver,address,username,password);
    
    var sql = "SELECT OBX3,OBX5 from table where column =" + erefID;
    var results = dbConn.executeCachedQuery(sql);
    
    var resultSize = results.size();
    
    logger.info('query results ' + results);
    logger.info('result size ' +resultSize);
    
    var obx3 = "";
    var obx5 = "";
    while(results.next()){
        var i=0
        obx3 = results.getString(1);
        logger.info('obx3 ' + obx3);
        obx5 = results.getString(2);
        logger.info('obx5 '+obx5);
        
        while(i<resultSize)
        {
            createSegment('OBX', tmp,i);
            tmp['OBX'][i]['OBX.1']['OBX.1.1'] = i;
            tmp['OBX'][i]['OBX.3']['OBX.3.1'] = obx3;
            tmp['OBX'][i]['OBX.5']['OBX.5.1'] = obx5;
    
            i++;
            
        }
    }
    
    dbConn.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Switched around the while statements, works now

```
while(i<resultSize){
        var i=0
        obx3 = results.getString(1);
        logger.info('obx3 ' + obx3);
        obx5 = results.getString(2);
        logger.info('obx5 '+obx5);
        
        while(results.next()){
        
            createSegment('OBX', tmp,i);
            tmp['OBX'][i]['OBX.1']['OBX.1.1'] = i;
            tmp['OBX'][i]['OBX.3']['OBX.3.1'] = obx3;
            tmp['OBX'][i]['OBX.5']['OBX.5.1'] = obx5;
    
            i++;
            
        }
    }
```