# Problem with creating multiple OBX segments in Mirth Connect

Tags: javascript, typeof, mirth, hl7-v2

**I have DB from where I'm getting my data of measurements.** This is my code for looping through my measurements and adding them to OBX segments:

```js
//getting MeasurementsData
    var data = msg['measurements_measurement_data'].toString();
    logger.info(data);  
    
    //inserting data in dictionary
    var dictMeasurements = {};
    for (var measurement in data) {
        dictMeasurements[measurement] = data[measurement];
    }
    
    var dictSize = Object.keys(dictMeasurements).length;
    var measureResult;
    var measureType;
    var counter = 1;
    
    //Creating OBX measurements segments
    while (counter <= dictSize) {
        for (var key in dictMeasurements) {
            //measure and result of measure
            measureType = key;
            measureResult = dictMeasurements[key];
    
            createSegment('OBX', tmp, counter);
            
            tmp['OBX'][counter]['OBX.1']['OBX.1.1'] = counter;
            //ST-string or NM-numeric
            tmp['OBX'][counter]['OBX.2']['OBX.2.1'] = isNumeric(measureResult);
            tmp['OBX'][counter]['OBX.3']['OBX.3.1'] = ('ABI.' + measureType);
            tmp['OBX'][counter]['OBX.3']['OBX.3.2'] = measureType;
            tmp['OBX'][counter]['OBX.5']['OBX.5.1'] = measureResult;
            tmp['OBX'][counter]['OBX.11']['OBX.11.1'] = 'F';
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

If I run this code locally, it returns what I want (measurement type and its result), like:

*cuffSizeArmLeft
1

cuffSizeArmRight

1

diaArmLeft
66

diaArmRight
66*

But when I run it on MirthConnect chanel I get every letter from measure type in it's own column:

ST|ABI.0^0||{||||||F
OBX|2|ST|ABI.1^1||"||||||F
OBX|3|ST|ABI.2^2||c||||||F
OBX|4|ST|ABI.3^3||u||||||F
OBX|5|ST|ABI.4^4||f||||||F
OBX|6|ST|ABI.5^5||f||||||F
OBX|7|ST|ABI.6^6||S||||||F
OBX|8|ST|ABI.7^7||i||||||F
OBX|9|ST|ABI.8^8||z||||||F
OBX|10|ST|ABI.9^9||e||||||F
OBX|11|ST|ABI.10^10||A||||||F
OBX|12|ST|ABI.11^11||r||||||F
OBX|13|ST|ABI.12^12||m||||||F
OBX|14|ST|ABI.13^13||L||||||F
OBX|15|ST|ABI.14^14||e||||||F
OBX|16|ST|ABI.15^15||f||||||F
OBX|17|ST|ABI.16^16||t||||||F
OBX|18|ST|ABI.17^17||"||||||F

- and my key in for loop is returning some numbers instead of measurement type, like it does locally.

This is similar question, but it didn't helped me.
[Creating OBX segments from multiple DB rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68229792/creating-obx-segments-from-multiple-db-rows)

My another problem is that my function "isNumeric", is always returning a ST(string) instead a NM(numeric) type. Locally runs perfect.

```js
function isNumeric(result) {
    var reg = /^\d*\.?\d+$/;
    if (typeof(result) == 'number') { return 'NM'; }
    else { return 'ST'; }
}

console.log(isNumeric(140));  //return NM
console.log(isNumeric('test')); //return ST
```

**Thanks for your help!**

Comment: `data` is a string. I'm guessing that `msg['measurements_measurement_data']` should be an object. If so, remove the `.toString()`

Comment: I tried, but result is still the same.

Comment: parse it as a JSON then. 
`var data = JSON.parse(msg['measurements_measurement_data'].toString());`

Comment: Thank you, I will try that :)